# Abstract class dictionary in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to do a abstract class dictionary to store classes which extends a abstract class, not instances. But I have a problem.

```
abstract class  AbstractClass{
   foo(){
      // do someThing
   }
 }

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass{
    foo(){
        super.foo()
    }
}


interface ClassDictionary {
    [index:string]:  typeof AbstractClass
}


let dictionary : ClassDictionary = { "ONE" :  ConcreteClass }

new dictionary["One"]().foo() // Error. It can´t instance a abstrac class (of course)
```

So, how do you think I can get this?

I don't want to remove abstract modifier from AbstractClass because I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
abstract class  AbstractClass{
   foo(){
      // do someThing
   }
 }

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass{
    foo(){
        super.foo()
    }
}


interface ClassDictionary {
    [index:string]: new() => AbstractClass; // <---
}


let dictionary : ClassDictionary = { "ONE" :  ConcreteClass }

new dictionary["One"]().foo();
```

Comment: Instead of adding boilerplate, you should explain why this is different and how it works.

Comment: Thanks for quicky response. It seems a good solution but if I modify constructor

   constructor( foo:string){
       
   } 

I must modifty this:

 [index:string]: new( ...args) => AbstractClass; // <---

Due to I don´t know how many parameters will have child classes and this code does not show errors:

new dicctionary["One"]().foo(); // No arguments but ¿ok?

Comment: Since you don't know which class you're constructing, you should be writing whatever construct signature you intend to invoke with (in your case, 0 arguments) instead of `...args`.

Comment: @JoséCarlosLama: If you don't know how many arguments the constructors take, your code is fundamentally unsafe.  You need to fix that.

Answer (score -1):

```
abstract class  AbstractClass{



   constructor( foo:string){

   } 

   foo(){
      // do someThing
   }
 }

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass{


   constructor( foo:string, bar: number){
       super(foo)
   } 

    foo(){
        super.foo()
    }
}


interface ClassDictionary {
    [index:string]: new( ...args) => AbstractClass; // <---
}


let dictionary : ClassDictionary = { "ONE" :  ConcreteClass }

new dictionary["One"]().foo(); // No error but It needs some arguments
```

Comment: Don't answer your question in order to add more info to the question, instead edit your question